# How to store the data with a new name after removing missing data in r

Tags: r, dataframe

Using R, I want to remove NA and -999 values in a specific column of variable `V1` and save the cleaned data with a new name `df2`.
Eventually I want to see the summary of the new dataset, but don't know how to assign a new name.

I have tried so far:

```
df <- read_excel("long.xls")

df$V1<- ifelse(df$V1== -999, NA, df$V1) 

summary(df2)
```

Comment: Make a copy first by assigning to a new name, then modify the copy. `df2 <- df; df2$V1<- ifelse(df2$V1== -999, NA, df2$V1); summary(df2)`

Comment: or `df2 <- transform(df1, V1 = ifelse(V1 == -999, V1[NA], V1))` or `df2 <- dplyr::mutate(V1 = if_else(V1 == -999, V1[NA], V1))`.

Comment: @r2evans I haven’t seen `V1[NA]` before - I’m guessing that gives a vector of `NA`s the same length as `V1`?

Comment: Yes. It's a trick to deal with two nuances of R: (1) there are at least 6 different types of `NA`; and (2) many tools don't deal well when given the wrong class, namely `if_else`, `case_when` (both dplyr) and many others. It guarantees _unambiguously_ that whatever class `V1` may be, the `NA` you get out of `V1[NA]` will always be the same class. This is to guard against changes in class, such as demonstrated by `class(ifelse(c(T,F), 1:2, NA))` versus `class(ifelse(c(F,F), 1:2, NA))`.

Comment: Oh wow - I’ve spent lots of time trying to write functions to do exactly this — return `NA`s of the same class and type as the input — with limited success. Never realized there was a built-in way of doing so. Thank you!

Comment: @zephryl, it's hinted (under-stated) in `?[` with *"returns 'NA' in the corresponding element of a logical, integer, numeric, complex or character result"* in the "NAs in indexing" section. I started doing it before finding that reference (so I guessed right :-).